# How to Insert value into Android SQLite DataBase without OnClick?

Tags: android, sqlite

Does someone knows how implement insert values into SQLite Database without On Click function.

There are many example show how to insert , update , delete and select function , but it's BUTTON OnClickListener , I want to know only insert without BUTTON OnClickListener.

For example : I have a random number like :

```
private void randomNumber() {
   int max = 100;
   int min = 1;
   Random random = new Random();
   int p = random.nextInt(max)%(max-min+1) + min;
   float pf = p / 100f;
}
```

I know how to insert float pf into SQLite by :

```
private void add(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Speed, pf);
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}
```

but add function is OnClick :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
         case R.id.btnAdd:
               add();
               break;
           .......
           .......
     }
}
```

I don't want to press add button to insert values into database , I want to automatic insert value into database . help me , please.

Comment: What's stopping you from copy pasting the code inside the onButtonClick listener to a function that will be called whenever you want it?

Comment: `add()` inserts the value, then invoke it from wherever you like

Comment: to insert values without `onClick` simply call the code from somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usee add() mehtod into onCreate();

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
   //call method whenever you want to add random number
   //whenever application open one number genrated and added to database

   add();

   //if you want to add multiple number to database just add loop like
  //loop will add five randome number
   for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
       add();
    }


}
```

if you want to add randome number when you come from the another activity you can call add() mehtod under onResume

```
public void onResume(){
  super.onResume();
  // put your code here...
  add();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Razgriz mentioned just call add() anywhere else.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
   ....
   add();
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to insert data into database ?
Any specific Event or any specific condition ?

You just need to call add() and values will be inserted.